# JettyGwtSpringSample web application

Tags: java, thread-safety, spring, gradle, gwt

I just created a sample project using Spring 3.x, Jetty 9.x, GWT 2.5.1 and Gradle [here](https://github.com/krishnaraj/JettyGwtSpringSample). It's a slightly modified version of the 'Greeting' GWT application from Google, the only change being that RPC calls are handled by a spring controller.

It would be really great if someone can review it, I am particularly apprehensive of injecting the `GwtRpcController` into the `GreetingServiceImpl`. Should I be worried about any thread safety issues?

**Main Controller**

```
@Controller
public class GwtRpcController extends RemoteServiceServlet {

@Autowired 
private ServletContext servletContext;

@Autowired
private RemoteService remoteService;

private Class<?> remoteServiceClass;

private HttpServletRequest request;

@RequestMapping(value = "/jettygwtspringsampleapp/*.rpc")
public ModelAndView handleRequest( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception {
    super.doPost( request, response );
    return null;
}

@Override
public String processCall( String payload ) throws SerializationException {
    try {

        RPCRequest rpcRequest = RPC.decodeRequest( payload, this.remoteServiceClass );

        // delegate work to the spring injected service
        return RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse( this.remoteService, rpcRequest.getMethod(), rpcRequest.getParameters() );
    } catch ( IncompatibleRemoteServiceException ex ) {
        getServletContext().log( "An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.", ex );
        return RPC.encodeResponseForFailure( null, ex );
    }
}

@Override
public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    return servletContext;
}

public void setServletContext( ServletContext servletContext ) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}

public void setRemoteService( RemoteService remoteService ) {
    this.remoteService = remoteService;
    this.remoteServiceClass = this.remoteService.getClass();
}

public HttpServletRequest getThreadLocalHttpRequest() {
    return getThreadLocalRequest();
}

}
```

**Service implementation**

```
@Configuration
public class GreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {

@Autowired
GwtRpcController rpcController;

public String greetServer( String input ) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Verify that the input is valid.
    if ( !FieldVerifier.isValidName( input ) ) {
        // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
        // the client.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Name must be at least 4 characters long" );
    }

    String serverInfo = rpcController.getServletContext().getServerInfo();
    String userAgent = rpcController.getThreadLocalHttpRequest().getHeader( "User-Agent" );

    // Escape data from the client to avoid cross-site script vulnerabilities.
    input = escapeHtml( input );
    userAgent = escapeHtml( userAgent );

    return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running " + serverInfo + ".<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>" + userAgent;
}
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Just some generic note about the code:

1. If the parameter called `input` contains a name you should rename it to `name` to express its purpose.
2. Method names should be verbs. I would rename `greetServer` to `serveGreeting` or `doGreeting`. (Check [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language, Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and *Clean Code*, page 25.)
3. Comments like this are rather just noise:

   ```
   // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
   // the client.
   ```

   It's pretty obvious from the code itself, so I'd remove the comment. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
4. I'd move the complete validation logic to the `FieldVerifier` class (or another helper class or helper method) for better reusability and higher abstraction. It also would make the `greetServer` method more compact.
5. The `isValidName` could be a little bit shorter with the null-safe Apache Commons Lang [`StringUtils.length`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#length%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

   ```
   public static boolean isValidName(String name) {
       return StringUtils.length(name) > 3;
   }
   ```
6. Usage of Google Guava would make `checkName` more compact:

   ```
   public static void checkName(final String name) {
       checkArgument(isValidName(name), 
           "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
   }
   ```

   (See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)
7. ```
   public String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       ...
   }
   ```

   `IllegalArgumentException` is a `RuntimeException`, so declaring them in the method signature is not mandatory, you could omit it:

   ```
   public String greetServer(String name) {
       ...
   }
   ```